# PAM: pam_get_authtok return PAM_BAD_ITEM

Tags: linux, debian, pam

I'm trying to write my own PAM module:

```
int pam_sm_setcred(pam_handle_t* handle, int flags, int argc, const char** argv)
{
     return PAM_SUCCESS;
}

int pam_sm_acct_mgmt(pam_handle_t* handle, int flags, int argc, const char** argv)
{
     return PAM_SUCCESS;
}

int pam_sm_authenticate(pam_handle_t* handle, int flags, int argc, const char** argv)
{
     ...

     retval = pam_get_user(handle, &username, "Username: ");
     if (retval != PAM_SUCCESS)
     {
          return retval;
     }

     passwd = getpwnam(username);
     if (!passwd)
     {
          return PAM_USER_UNKNOWN;
     }

     retval = pam_get_authtok(handle, PAM_AUTHTOK, &password, "Password: ");
     if (retval != PAM_SUCCESS)
     {
          return retval;
     }

     printf("Welcome to Hell, %s : %s\n", username, password);
     return PAM_SUCCESS;
}
```

And it's works when i put .so library into /lib/security and added at the top of the pam file (/etc/pam.d/common-auth) these lines:

```
auth sufficient mypam.so
account sufficient mypam.so
```

For example: when i try to open some file under sudo, it's works correctly.

But I also trying to write small executable test:

```
int main(...)
{
     pam_conv conv = {misc_conv, NULL};
     pam_start("test", NULL, &conv, &handle);
     pam_sm_authenticate(handle, 0, 0, NULL);
     ...
}
```

And in this case, when execution comes to `pam_get_authtok(...)`, it's return error code 29 (PAM_BAD_ITEM).

What am I doing wrong?